# Grant user error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Within oracle apex 5.1.2 I have been experimenting with security features relating to grants, using the managing user tab i managed to create users and allocated these users end-user account types. My problem begins when I attempt to GRANT these users privileges to defined tables within my schema I hit an error when I for instance:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *SCHEMA.*TABLE TO CREATEDUSER
```

ORA-01917: user or role ' CREATEDUSER' does not exist

I can't quite workout why this is happening, I've researched the issue however I have not come across an understandable resolution

Comment: How did you create these users? Using the database command `create user`? Or as users within APEX?

Comment: These users were created within apex via the user accounts form found on the Managing users page. As it seems with this school account I cannot create new users via SQL COMMAND due to me having insufficient privileges, meaning I didn't really know how to test whether my grants worked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is because Apex users [are not database users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26899325/6854914).

> …APEX users are not database users. Apex users are pseudo users that have schema grants by the Apex administration area

Apex users are stored in Apex tables and [you can create groups to restrict access to various parts of an application](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12512/aadm_users.htm#AEADM154).

Comment: With these groups will I have the ability to test the privileges users can have on a table using sql? as I know through using an application I could just simply create an access control administration page however this seems too easy and simplistic?

Comment: I don't think Apex users have privileges on database objects directly — you need to control access in the application.